# How does conversion to ASP.Net Framework 4.5.1 affect self-hosted web services?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, asp.net-mvc-5, self-hosting

The solution I am migrating is Framework 4, and it has a Service Host Website that the web application references; the svc files under the ServiceHost project point to another project that is a Class Library. This project houses the implementation of the data contracts and service contracts, as well as the service host factory classes pointed at by the svc code.

When running the solution, the Wcf Service Host launches but the services listed in Wcf Service Host are always Stopped. Clicking on the service gives this error: "The service cannot be started. This service has no endpoint defined. Please add at least one endpoint for the service in config file and try again." Visual Studio gives this error: "There was no endpoint listening at [endpoint address] that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action." Browsing using the service's URL gives an HTTP 404 error.

I've tried setting multipleSiteBindingsEnabled to true and then use relative addresses; using bindings other than basicHttpBinding; changing the value of the endpoint address in the server's Web.config blank to empty string. I've deleted the old service references in the client application and added them again; the port we're using is not blocked, I've set VS2015 to run as administrator and I've ruled out firewalls and anti-virus software blocking the service. I also followed [this article](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2013/06/hosting-wcf-service-inside-aspnet-mvc.html) and added the two routes to be ignored, but still no go.

My question is, is there some incompatibility between .Net 4.5 and older self-hosted web services? What could be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Do you have both projects set to startup? Under the solution property's -> startup project make sure "Multiple startup Projects" enabled and have you service host project action set to start. Then when you start the site it will also start your hosted service as well.

Comment: I did as you described, I'm still getting the same error. I've also tried setting useLegacySerializerGeneration to true, no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got things to work; I did the conversion process over and did three things differently - first, I made sure not to edit any of the values in the assemblies section of the Web.config file of my web application. Second, I made sure to only add the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc NuGet package to my web application, and not to the class libraries. Lastly, I only updated those references that needed changing - these were Micosoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, and EntityFramework.

For Micosoft.Office.Interop.Excel I added a reference to the VS2015 COM assembly, and for EntityFramework I installed the NuGet package. Hopefully this will help someone else.